# PHP define doesn't work in other files

Tags: php, constants, global, configuration-files

I have a config.php file which defines my database host name, database name, database username, and database password. Unfortunately when I require this file, my defines don't carry over. So, if I have this in config.php:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'example');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

And this in connect.php:

```
require_once 'config.php';
echo DB_HOST;
```

I get nothing. How do I extend these defines so they will be available in files that include config.php?

Comment: are the two files in the same directory?

Comment: What is the error it's outputting? Maybe there's a specific reason!

Comment: It's not outputting any error. I can echo out the defined constants inside config.php but in connect.php I can't.

Comment: Reason might be, config.php file not included properly, please make sure you have used the proper path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');
```